# How do I Moq DbContext.ExecuteStoredProcedure?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, stored-procedures, moq

I have the following problem to solve. I am trying to set up a unit test that tests a method that uses the following way of calling a stored procedure through the entity framework. Is there a way i can test this without making changes in code?

```
          var kinds = ((DbContext)Context).ExecuteStoredProcedure<ObjectType>
            ("schema.procedure", new
            {

                Type = typeString,
                Search = search,
                Category = category,
            });
```

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Comment: I think the version we are using is 5.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no

Longer version: what is it that you want to *test* in your snippet of code? It is not clear by your question. But in general intruding a new abstraction (level (in .net a interface for data access)) is a good decision.

Comment: I agree with dependency injection but I am being asked to test that snippet of code without performing any code changes. Which is what i am trying to figure out how to do.

Comment: @Avennite one of the only ways to test that code is to point it to an actual database that has that stored procedure. Which puts you into integration testing. So restore a backup and test away.